# Is there a way to explain or prove that there is not a single order of operations on the real numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, philosophy

Given that addition and multiplication are both commutative and associative, Expressions containing only addition or multiplication can be evaluated in a any order. However, when the operation changes from addition to multiplication or from multiplication to division it is necessary to specify which operation to perform first because multiplication distributes over addition.

This seems somewhat unsatisfactory to me because it relies on the assumption that there is no actual preferred order of evaluation built into the real numbers. I was wondering if I might have some help fleshing this out in a way that explicitly addresses the putative assumption that there is no explicit order of operations on the real numbers.

---

Starting with the field axioms, can one prove that there is a single interpretation for unbracketed real-number expressions?

Comment: The multiplication is an addition but the addition is not a multiplication.

Comment: To correct for this, brackets are used to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I'm not quite sure the tag ([tag:abstract-algebra]) is appropriate.

Comment: How is a abstract algebra not an appropriate tag? The question is about how to derive a statement from the axioms of a field.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima why not do the more primitive operation first?

Comment: to be fair there's not really one built into the integers either. it was just that we picked one that worked so that things like 1+2*3-4/5 didn't have 24 possible answers potentially as accepted answers so people wouldn't argue about which is correct.

Comment: This question strikes me as rather philosophical. I'm not saying it's off-topic, though.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks so now I added the philosophy tag.

Comment: But it's not really which order of operations is better. Rather, it is allot whether order of operations can be derived from the field axioms. To me, the question "is the continuum hypothesis provable in ZFC?" isn't terribly philosophical.

Comment: I think this question is not about properties of the reals or the integers so much as about properties of notations for computations.  Consider these alternatives to parenthesized formulas for representing computations:  evaluation trees and reverse Polish notation.  Neither of these need "order of operations".

Comment: my point in my previous comment is that without a given order of operations  we can get the following from 1+2*3-4/5:

1,41/5,31/5,3/5 .... all by simply changing the order of operations (aka by making the implied parentheses different).

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern From the way the question is phrased, it is very much unapparent that you want to discuss the axioms of the reals.

Comment: I think you need to consider that brackets were added to ensure order was followed. For example, a/b(c+d) is not well formed and therefore has no solution. To correct this we either mean:
1) a/(b(c+d))    OR
2) (a/b)(c+d)
To write it simply as a/b(c+d) is committing a math crime

Comment: It's purely a matter of notation.  Parenthesis are put in to indicate order.  If parenthises are left out is it ambiguous.  So pick a convention... ***ANY*** convention and stick to it. We *could* do "left to right always" or "right to left always".  But As $a*(b+c) = (a*b) + (a*c)$ by the distributive property there is a motivation to multiplication take precedence over order.

Comment: Order of operations is pure convention. For the most part it's arbitrary and a matter of convenience. You have to separate the notation from the actual mathematics. Fields don't care what order you apply their operations in, you end up with compositions of functions of two variables. If there's ambiguity, it's not well defined.

Comment: Order of operations, originally, was developed so that someone could write out an expression knowing that anyone who read it would evaluate the expression exactly one way. The actual rules were worked out as what seemed to be the most natural interpretation, but I'm sure that there was a lot of argument while this was happening. Now, order of operations is also just as important for computer programmers.  There are other ways of writing out expressions. Reverse Polish Notation (RPN) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could simply say as convention that all operations of more than two operands must absolutely have parenthesis around every pair and that if the parenthesis are missing they expression is meaningless.

So $a + b*c + d*e +f$ (as we know it) must be written as $(((a + (b*c)) + (d*e))+f)$  This is, of course, tedious.

We could have as a convention that we always go from left to right, always.  So the expression $a + b*c + d*e + f$ would now mean $((a+b)*c + d)*e + f$ and to write the expression we meant we'd have to writh $a + (b*c) + (d*e) + f$.

This is perfectly acceptable.

However given that we have the distributive law that $a(b+c) = (ab) + (ac)$ there is an incentive to view $a*c + b*c$ so $(a*c) + (b*c) = (a+b)*c$ rather than as $(a*c + b)*c = a*c^2 + (b*c)$.  Our convention is consistent, less capricious, and usefl and insightful.

Comment: But my question was whether the convention we use is provably the only one constituent with the axioms of real numbers.

Comment: They *all* are constituent with the axioms of the real numbers.  But ours using precedence of multiplication has direct bearing to the distributive law.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we restrict ourselves to just multiplication and addition. The distributive law usually reads:
$$a(b+c) = ab+ac$$

Which we understand to mean:
$a(b+c)=(ab)+(ac)$, not $a(b+a)c$ or $(a(b+c))a$. This is as close as I can find to an implied order of operations from the field axioms. Personally I'd argue this is the writers abusing a standard, not intended as an actual definition for order of operations on the reals. Nobody would object to field axioms in post script reading: $$\cdot (a, + (b, c)) = + (\cdot (a ,b), \cdot (a, c)).$$ (parenthesis added for notational prettiness, they aren't required for this to be unambiguous)